# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type when accessing struct

Tags: c

I am not sure why this is happening. I am doing an assignment and the code somehow does not compile.

This is the header file

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t jump_code[3];   /* Ignore this */
    char oemname[8];        /* Might as well ignore this one too */
    uint8_t ssize[2];       /* Sector size in bytes */
    uint8_t csize;          /* Cluster size in sectors */
    uint8_t reserved[2];    /* Number of reserved sectors for boot sectors */
    uint8_t numfat;         /* Number of FATs */
    uint8_t numroot[2];     /* Number of Root directory entries */
    uint8_t sectors16[2];   /* number of sectors in the file system */
    uint8_t media[1];       /* Media descriptor type */
    uint8_t sectperfat16[2];/* Number of sectors per FAT */
    uint8_t sectpertrack[2];/* Number of sectors per track */
    uint8_t heads[2];       /* Number of heads */
    uint8_t prevsect[2];    /* Number of sectors before FS partition */
    uint8_t ignore[482];    /* Ignore these */
} boot_sect_t;
```

This is the part that gives the error:

```
struct boot_sect_t* boot = malloc(sizeof(boot_sect_t));
boot->ssize[0] = buffer[11]; //error here
boot->ssize[1] = buffer[12]; //error here
```

The error is:

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type when accessing struct

Comment: what is 
the type of `buffer` ?

Comment: @Jefffrey i think he put that as question title only. First timer common. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
struct boot_sect_t* boot = malloc(sizeof(boot_sect_t));
```

to

```
boot_sect_t* boot = malloc(sizeof(boot_sect_t));
```

`boot_sect_t` is already a `typedef`. no need to write `struct boot_sect_t`.